# laravel route with any character until next /

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-route

i have created a route in laravel

```
$stagechapter="[1-8]-.*";
$stagestage="[0-9]-.*";

Route::get('/{lang}/{chapter?}/{stage?}', 'StageController@Listing')->where('lang', $langs)->where("chapter",$stagechapter)->where("stage",$stagestage);
```

I want any character after the - until next /, the problem is that $chapter is capturing both directories,... So, when i write

/en/1-chapter1/1-stage1 in browser i get $lang="en", $chapter="1-chapter1/1-stage1" and $stage NULL.

I understand that .* expresion gets anything until the end so ...so, whats the right regular expresion to stop at / and get $chapter="1-chapter1" and $stage="1-stage1"?

I get

Comment: Use `[^/]*`..........

Comment: thanks and sorry, i was searching only about laravel routing and didnt check in regular expresions :P